# How to get coordinates values while long tap/hold in ionic google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, gesture

I am trying to get coordinates while tap or hold events in ionic from the Google Maps.

While holding I am getting values in browser console not getting in device.

How to clear this issue?. I need to get values while holding/taping in mobile apps using ionic framework [google maps].

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $ionicGesture) {

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
        });

        var posOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };
        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            $rootScope.currentlat = lat;
            $rootScope.currentlong = long;
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            $rootScope.myLatlng = myLatlng;
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            $scope.map = map;
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: $scope.map
            });

            var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#map'));
            $ionicGesture.on('hold', function(e){
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    alert('hold happens');
                   google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');
                   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                      alert(event.latLng);
                   });
                });
            }, element);

           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
            });

            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }, function (err) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log(err);
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that your using

`$ionicGesture.on('hold')`

Iconic uses Cordova and Cordova google maps has its own event handler as the "map" is in native view not JavaScript related. You can read up in more detail [here](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map#how-does-the-plugin-work).

So once your device is ready

```
  var map       = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions),
      longClick = plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_LONG_CLICK;

  map.on(longClick, function (latLng) {

    var selectedLatLocation = latLng.lat.toString();
    var selectedLongLocation = latLng.lng.toString();

    alert(selectedLatLocation, selectedLongLocation);


  });
```